# What class are JavaScript variables assigned to?

Tags: javascript

I'm making a web app. I've noticed that functions declared in JavaScript can be found in the window class on the page, e.g.:

JS file included in HTML:

```
function myFunc(args) {
    // Some code
}
```

In developer tools console:

```
window.myFunc
f myFunc(args) {
    // Some code...
```

But for variables...
JS file included in HTML:

```
let myVar;
```

In developer tools console:

```
window.myVar
undefined
```

Which class are the variables I declare assigned to?

Comment: Google for "javascript scope"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using var or just declaring a function instead of using let or const, then your functions will be added to the window object, not a class. If you want a detailed look at this, search "var vs let and const". There's a lot of really good articles that explain them each in length.